# method for select (column_name) where (some single condition)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have looked and looked, but I cannot find a method that will allow me to select a specific column based on a single condition (that does not involve a string query). The condition is arbitrary, but the column name is always the same. Below is my most recent (and desperate) attempt to better illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
@notExists = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", :company)
```

Ok, the query was correct, I was forgetting to use the '=>' in the below code. However, that now yeilds an error because :company is evaluating to be 'company'. According to the list of params in the server output window, its value is 'sample'.

Edit: full content

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable

   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes
   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company

   validates :company, :presence => true
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

   after_save :correspond


   def correspond
     @notExists = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", :company)

     if @notExists.empty?
       c = Company.new(:name => :company)
       c.save
     end
   end

 end
```

To see the full solution to this issue, please see dmarkow's answer below. One change was necessary to make it tick:

```
def correspond
  c = Company.find_or_create_by_name(self.company)
end
```

Comment: Please post the **full** content of this method in your model, that way we can see what the actual parameter names are.

Comment: Perfect, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is preventing your code from working is that you're trying to use `:company` which translates as a string instead of a variable.

**Edit**:

Your correspond method should be defined with a parameter and the first line of the method should use that parameter like so:

```
def correspond(user)
  @notExists = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", user.company)
```

However, this is a much cleaner way of doing this -- it will only create the company if it doesn't exist:

```
def correspond(user)
  c = Company.find_or_create_by_name(user.company)
end
```

Comment: This code is in a model; using params gives me a name error.. I am about to edit my post, the other answerer has lead me to believe that the error may be in another part of the code.

Comment: What's I'm getting at is that `where("name = ?", :company)` is always going to equate to "name = 'company'" rather than using whatever variable you're trying to use. Can you post the full method that's using this code?

Comment: hahaha, you wrote what I edited to complain about. Good call! However, is params out of the question as it is throwing NameError? or just another mistake on my part?

Comment: Thanks, I love finding out about methods like find_or_create... they are what make ruby/rails great. I am accepting this answer as it is mostly correct. Only one change is necessary. I have edited the original question to include the modification code.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have seems fine. If you want to get just the column value, you could do:

```
company = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", :company).first
value = company && company.name
```

Comment: Hmm... and this returns nil when there is no corresponding entry, right? If my query is correct then something strange is afoot..

Answer (score 0):

```
@notExists = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", :company)
```

will return `[]` if no matching records exist

```
@notExists = Company.select("name").where("name = ?", :company).first
```

will return `nil` if no matching records exist

so if you are relying on it to be `nil` if the record does not exist you need the second one.

you could test the first one with `@notExists.empty?`

Comment: Also I do agree with @dmarkow that the where clause is suspect as written and may not be doing what you think it is

Comment: Good tip, I will change to .empty?